# I can't modify the screen brightness on Xubuntu 13.10

Tags: nvidia, xubuntu, brightness, vaio

I got this problem with brightness on my fresh xubuntu 13.10 install..
It ain't inc/decrease the screen brightness when pressing  Fn+F5/F6 !!

I've tried some solutions like setting these values in  the  */etc/default/grub*  file and sudo updating grub (this worked for me on my previous xubuntu 13.04 install)

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

But still not working though :/

I have got a Sony VAIO VPCEJ3B1E running xubuntu 13.10 x64bit
and an NVidia GeForce 410M and using the propritory drivers 319

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem with Ubuntu 13.10 install. My brightness shortcut keys (Fn + F5/F6) worked in 12.10 as well as 13.04.

I am using Sony Vaio SVE15113ENB with VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09). 
Any help is appreciated.

I have tried:

1. Installing Additional Drivers from Software Centre
2. Finding /etc/X11/Xorg.con file but it does not exist for me.
3. Modifying grub file and sudo updating grub and then reboot.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the brightness via command line using:

```
xbacklight -set 100
```

If that works, trying binding a global keyboard shortcut to

```
xbacklight -inc 5
```

and

```
xbacklight -dec 5
```