# Unable to change display brightness with Function keys or Brightness and Lock application in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: drivers, 13.10, intel-graphics, brightness

I am having problem with Ubuntu 13.10 brightness control. My brightness shortcut keys (Fn + F5/F6) worked in 12.10 and 13.04 but they have stopped working in 13.10.

I am using Sony Vaio SVE15113ENB with VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09). Any help is appreciated.

I have tried following options, but none of them has worked so far:

1. Installing Additional Drivers from Software Centre
2. Finding `/etc/X11/Xorg.con` file for editing but it does not exist for me.
3. Visited Software & Updates > Additional Drivers tab, but it shows nothing saying 'No additional drivers available' and 'No proprietary drivers are in use'.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

- Execute `$ sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
- Modify the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"`

- Save the changes.
- Execute `$ sudo update-grub`
- Reboot.

Archlinux Wiki on brightness controls [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/backlight).

Comment: Thanks @Pavel for your response. I tried this approach, with an additional reference to another similar question http://askubuntu.com/questions/366710/i-cant-modify-the-screen-brightness-on-xubuntu-13-10

Comment: But it did not work. Is there anything I could check with driver installations? Or does Ubuntu installation come packaged with sufficient drivers to make all standard features of a laptop work out-of-box?

Comment: Your laptop may need some more tweaking as mentioned on this Arch wiki page in the ACPI section: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/backlight. Try it.

Comment: I am able to set brightness from Terminal using commands `echo 4000 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` and `cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`. Could you suggest a way to trigger them using Fn+F5 or Fn+F6?

Comment: Before we reach there: have you tried ALL grub file options from the Arch manual? And can you change brightness from System Settings > Brightness & Lock?

Comment: Yes @Pavel I tried all combinations of `acpi_osi="!Windows 2012" acpi_backlight=vendor` , `acpi_backlight=legacy` and  `acpi_osi=Linux` but I am not able to make it work.

Comment: I am not able to change brightness from _Brightness & Lock_ application.

Comment: You can check this entry for assigning keys to backlight function. You'll probably need to install xbacklight to do it: http://askubuntu.com/questions/273045/how-to-use-xbacklight-with-brightness-keys-in-a-vaio. But I'm puzzled that controls work via terminal but not via the Brightness & Lock applet. Such scenario not even mentioned in debugging manuals.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11492/discussion-between-ninad116-and-pavel)